# Как в одном запросе SQL получить все значения с разными условиями с сортировкой

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Структура таблицы `settings`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

Дамп данных таблицы `settings`

```
INSERT INTO `settings` (`id`, `name`, `value`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'title', 'Qeekly', 'core'),
(2, 'description', 'Твой собственный маленький мир', 'core'),
(3, 'keywords', 'minecraft,сервер,комплекс,qeekly,майнкрафт', 'core'),
(4, 'copyright', '«При копировании материалов с сайта, оставайтесь людьми — указывайте ссылку на источник!» Qeekly ©', 'core'),
(5, 'charset', 'UTF-8', 'core'),
(6, 'offline', '0', 'core'),
(7, 'template', 'default', 'core'),
(8, 'support', 'support@qeekly.ru', 'mail'),
(9, 'noreply', 'noreply@qeekly.ru', 'mail'),
(10, 'news', '3', 'lvl'),
(11, 'pages', '4', 'lvl'),
(12, 'actions', '4', 'lvl'),
(13, 'profile', '2', 'lvl'),
(14, 'news', '3', 'publish'),
(15, 'pages', '4', 'publish'),
(16, 'comments', '0', 'publish');
```

Теперь собственно к вопросу. Мне нужно в ОДНОМ sql запросе получить все значения поля value  `where type=core`, затем c `type=lvl` и т.д.

Примерно представляю так все:

```
SELECT `value` 
FROM `settings` 
WHERE `type` = 'core' as Core AND `type` = 'lvl' as Lvl AND `type` = 'publish' as Publish
```

Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Возможно ли такое или следует создавать несколько одинаковых запросов с разными where?

Вот тот же самый код в нескольких sql:

```
SELECT `value` FROM `settings` WHERE `type` = 'core'
SELECT `value` FROM `settings` WHERE `type` = 'lvl'
SELECT `value` FROM `settings` WHERE `type` = 'publish'
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46567/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-potter-----sql---).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на основе комментариев к вопросу, убедительная просьба переделать вопрос так, что бы он действительно спрашивал о том, чем нужно :)

```
$rename=array('OFFLINE'=>'OFFLINE_STATUS','TEMPLATE'=>'TEMPLATE_NAME');
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT name, type, value FROM settings');
while($row=$result->fetch_array()) {
 $name=strtoupper($row['name']);
 if($row['type']=='lvl' || $row['type']=='publish') {
   $name=$name.'_'.strtoupper($row['type']);
 }
 if(array_key_exists($name, $rename)) $name=$rename[$name];
 define($name,$row['value']);
}
```

Comment: Это конечно не идеально для меня, ибо ну не хотелось бы в таблице писать вместе просто template - template_name и вместо простого offline - offline_status.
Однако если по-другому никак, я благодарю Вас, ведь это определенно то, что мне нужно.

Comment: @DmitryPotter Вот для этого я под ответом и написал, что если какие то имена не совпадают, то надо преобразовать их. Опять же на клиенте. Дописал в код пример такого преобразования. Надеюсь ничего не напутал, на глаз писал, на php не работаю :)

Comment: решение мягко говоря не очень. Лишний код. Уж лучше жить с кривой :-) таблицей, чем с корявым кодом. :-)
Но да это должно работать)

Comment: @DmitryPotter А ваш предыдущий код хотите сказать был не корявым, с явными $settings[100500], необходимостью правильной сортировки вывода из БД (не дай бог какой нибудь записи не окажется и т.п.). Кстати никто не мешает в БД завести таблицу преобразования имен, подклеить ее по left join прямо в этом запросе и брать имя для php из нее

Comment: мой код был написан для того, чтобы СЕБЕ показать, чего я хочу, затем я обратился за помощью, чтобы реализовать все грамотно, а не оставлять так, как кое-как работает. :)